# Showing a set of vectors being a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V=\{(x,y,z) \vert x-3y+2z=0 \}$, $V$ is also a subset of $\mathbb R^3$.

The question is how do we check if $V$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$, and how do we describe $V$ geometrically.

I represented $V$ explicitly, $V=\{(3s-2t,s,t) \vert s,t\in\mathbb R \}$

For $V$ to be considered a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$, it needs:

1. The zero vector in $V$, which can be easily shown by plugging in $s=0, t=0$
2. The vectors in $V$ must be closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

I am more confused about showing point 2 actually, I did it in this way.

$span(V)=\{C_1(3s-2t,s,t) \vert C_1,s,t\in\mathbb R \}$

Since $V$ can be repesented as a Linear Span, I can conclude that $V$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$. (This conclusion looks pretty dodgy to me, is my method correct?)

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Checking that $V$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication is straightforward, right? Just take $v,w\in V$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ and show that $v+w\in V$ and $\lambda v\in V$. Shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: There must be a typo right? You use triples $(x,y,z)$, whereas you are talking about $\mathbb{R}^2$? Anyway; just consider two solutions to the given equation and show that the sum is also a solution. Analogously for a scalar multiple (it is pretty straight forward, you did not need the transition to $s,t$). For the geometrical interpretation: what is the dimension of $V$?

Comment: $V$ may have dimension 2 but it is *not* a subset of $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Opps my bad, sorry, its edited...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $$a\in V, b \in V $$
We have by definition of $V$, there exists
$ s_1,s_2,t_1,t_2 \in \mathbb{R} $, such that
$$ a =(3s_1 - 2t_1,s_1,t_1) \in V, b = (3s_2 - 2t_2,s_2,t_2) \in V$$

Therefore 
$$ a + b =  (3s_1 - 2t_1 + 3t_2 - 2t_2 ,s_1+s_2,t_1+t_2) = (3(s_1 + t_2) - 2(t_1 +t_2) ,s_1+s_2,t_1+t_2)  $$

Now since $s_1 + s_2, t_1+t_2 \in \mathbb{R}$, again by the definition of $V$, we conclude that $a+b\in V$. This completes the proof that $V$ is closed under addition.

The scalar part follows exactly this pattern. Take arbitrarily $a \in V$ and $\lambda \in V$, verify that $\lambda a \in V$.

Comment: Do I go it like this way?

Let $\mathbf u\in V, \mathbf u=(3s_1-2t_1,s_1,t_1),s_1,t_1\in\mathbb R$.

Then $a\mathbf u=a(3s_1-2t_1,s_1,t_1)=(3as_1-2at_1,as_1,at_1), a\in \mathbb R$.

Since $a\in \mathbb R$ and $s_1,t_1\in\mathbb R$, we can conclude that $as_1-at_1,as_1,at_1\in\mathbb R$ as well, which implies that $a\mathbf u\in V$. Therefore $V$ is closed under scalar multiplication.

Comment: @Derp you are right. But you don't need to say that $as_1-at_1$ is a real number. A vector belongs to $V$, if and only if, the second and the third components are reals, and the first component can be written as the given linear combination (sum) of them. That also describes the geometric property ( in a rather abstract manner ) of $V$: once $s,t$ are given, the first component of the vector is totally determined. Therefore the space corresponds to a plane. It also suggests that the degree of freedom of $V$ is 2, as you can imagine, because only two components are "free".

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to note that $x-3y+2z=0$ can be written as:
$$
[x,y,z]^T\cdot[1,-3,2]^T=0
$$
(where $\cdot$ is the inner product), so we see that $V$ is a plane (of vectors $[x,y,z]^T$) orthogonal to the vector $[1,-3,2]^T$,. This gives a simple geometrical interpretation of $V$, and the proof that $ V$ is subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is simple because we have to prove that any linear combination of two vectors orthogonal to the same vector is orthogonal to this vector (but this is a consequence of the linearity of the inner product).